# Need some practical ideas to solve limitation of untappd API

Tags: javascript, database, api

I am currently writing my first "webapp" using javascript and the untappd API. The API documentation can be found here: https://untappd.com/api/docs#start

For those who don't know, untappd is an app that let's you checkin and rate beers with your phone. My plan is to make something that can recommend you a beer based on your own top rated beers in untappd! Just a hobby project.

So far I have been able to make the API call based on the username you fill in, parse the JSON data and display the top 10 beers in HTML cards on a webpage.

The next step would be to take certain characteristics of the top 10 beers (type of beer, brewery, rating for example) and use them as parameters to search for similar beers.

The problem however is that the "search beer" API of untappd seems quite limited. E.g. it doesnt return the global rating of the beers you find. Also you cannot search for a specific type of beer. For example if you query IPA - American" it might return a "IPA - Imperial/Double Black". You can find the untappd search beer API here: https://untappd.com/api/docs#beersearch

I was also thinking of using a different beer database to make the search however it doesnt seem there is a good public database around that I could use for this.

So basically I am looking for idea's. Maybe there's a better solution that I'm not seeing. Or some workaround that I can't think off.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [/beer/info/{bid} endpoint](https://untappd.com/api/docs#beerinfo) returns more details for each beer, so you could potentially perform the search, then iterate on each beer to grab additional details. Could use [Promises.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to help.

As far as filtering on specific type, unfortunately I think that is a calculated limitation in their public API to prevent API consumers from building robust integrations that may draw more attention to said integration. So you could also use the above endpoint to perform your own filtering on your end to only grab beers by type.

Comment: Ah thanks man. That's weird that I didnt see that endpoint before, how did you find it? 

So technically I would do my initial search, and then do an individual extended search on every result and filter for certain characteristics right?

Comment: @Basv yea that sounds about right. Definitely will require more time to process (not too significant), but really Untappd should allow filtering by more things in a search. Maybe you could email Untappd devs to allow for such filtering? [Untappd github](https://github.com/untappd) | Email: developers@nextglass.co

Comment: Thank you I might do that. However this project is mostly just for personal learning so I will attempt to make do at first :)